# Getting the IP address of a socket inside a close event handler

Tags: sockets, node.js

```
socket.on('data', function(data)
{
    console.log(socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort);
}

socket.on('close', function()
{
    console.log(socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort);
}
```

The log from the data handler displays `127.0.0.1:8000`.

The log from the close handler displays `undefined:undefined`.

I am trying to keep a list of connected sockets using IP:Port as the key.  If I don't know which one closed, how can I remove it from the list? How can I get the IP:Port of the closed socket after it's closed?

Comment: I would rethink that. You don't need it. The socket events give you the socket, and the socket gives you the IP address when it exists. The IP address on its own is useless without the socket. What's the map for?

Comment: There will be other data associated with each client, and the server will occasionally need to write to a specific client (not in response to a socket event), so I need to keep a list of the connected clients so I can address them individually

Comment: Then you need to find an attribute of the socket that doesn't change when you close it, to index your collection on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'm keeping track of the clients:

```
server.on('connect', function(socket)
{
    socket.key = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;
    clients[socket.key] = socket;

    socket.on('close', function()
    {
        delete clients[socket.key];
    }
}
```

Much thanks to mscdex in the Node.js IRC channel for suggesting this solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('connect', function()
{
   socket.address = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort;//save  the address in socket object
   console.log(socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort);
});
socket.on('data', function(data)
{
   console.log(socket.address );
});

socket.on('close', function()
{
  console.log(socket.address );
});
```

just keep the data associate with  the socket object.Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The remoteAddress property will be around even after disconnect once https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/8c38b07252d86f4eef91344f8df4f0c3e38bca35 is in a stable version of Node.js. io.js will have it in the next release: https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/1157